# How to exec a shell script from root monit (Mac)

Tags: shell, daemon, monit

I have setup my Mac's launchd to run this monit script:

```
set daemon 60

set logfile /var/log/monit.log

check host ac_server with address 127.0.0.1
    if failed port 3000
        then exec "/bin/bash -c '/Users/liren/ac-project/monit_task.sh'"
```

Basically at 60s interval, it will ping my Ruby on Rails server and execute the `monit_task.sh` script if server is down:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/Users/liren/ac-project/rails_app"
bundle exec "sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml" &
rails s -e production
```

---

monit script is located at `/usr/local/etc/monit/monitrc`, executed by my LaunchDaemon plist located at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`.

However, the shell script just doesn't get executed without any errors showing in log. Any idea why?

Comment: Run `type bundle` and `type rails` in Terminal, then put the correct full paths into your script.

Comment: omg wow @MarkSetchell that solves it! Thank you so much!! Please post that as an answer so that I can mark this question as answered :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am guessing the reason is because I installed my ruby through rbenv which doesn't have root permission. And when mac was booted, before logging in as user, my bash_profile was not sourced and therefore commands like `rails` was still unknown. Is that the right way to put this?

Comment: I'm not certain - all I would say is that processes started from `launchd` may run as a different user or with a different environment (including stuff from your profile) and thus may work differently from an interactive session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

```
type bundle
type rails
```

to find what is actually being run when you use those commands. Then put the full paths you discover as a result into your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/Users/liren/ac-project/rails_app"
/full/path/to/bundle exec "sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml" &
/full/path/to/rails s -e production
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply keep your current script without modifying and adding the full path and just edit something small in monitrc (it doesn't matter if it's linux or mac): here's my  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839285/7266232)

edit: don't forget to **chmod +x monit_task.sh**